# how to implement handler pause on another activity running this activity finish next continue handler

Tags: android

hi  i am implementing gallery application  in this gallery circular order draging left to right and right to left scrolling  i am using one handler on gallery rotation  another activity is gallery item clicking  handler automatically running  display the gallery image another action is click the gallery image display the clicked image 
  my problem gallery image clicking  and scorring  stop handler  and not scrolling clicking next continue to handler this functionality how can implemented please some suggestion its urgent some solution

clicking activity

```
 g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                try {
                    imageid=position;
                    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewlarge)).setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
                    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewImageName)).setText(imgNames[position]);
                     mp = MediaPlayer.create(SeaSpell.this,audioTrack[position]);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                }
            });
```

handler gallery rotation

```
 class RefreshHandler extends Handler {


        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {            
            SeaSpell.this.updateUI();
        }

        public void sleep(long delayMillis) {

            this.removeMessages(0);         
            if(isUpdateUI)
                sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
        }
}
public void updateUI(){
    try
    {
     getImages();// this method is gallery  rotation in circular manner
        mRedrawHandler.sleep(3000);

    }
```

how can solve this problem please send some solution  its urgent

Comment: please forward some suggestion i am new in android

Comment: please forward some suggestion this question related to handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  You can do whatever you want asynchronously, but EVERYTHING that updates UI must be run in UI Thread. So you should run that operations inside a Runnable with runOnUiThread function.this is process of your app